# Remove selected rows from a DataGrid when the user clicks on any other control

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to remove the selected items from a `DataGrid` when the user clicks on any other control in the `UserControl`. The grid has selection mode as "Extended".

I thought of oneapproach

LostFocus event on the `DataGrid` or the same event on `DataGridCell`:- But this event is called whenever I select any row in the grid. So I can't remove selected items here.

Comment: I am assuming that you have a UserControl having multiple controls, one of them is a DataGrid in question. And you want selected items to be removed if you click any other control apart from DataGrid in your UC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FrameworkElement.PreviewGotKeyboardFocusEvent` and handle it at the root which is UserControl in your case like this :

```
<UserControl  ... FrameworkElement.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="FrameworkPreviewGotKeyboardFocus" />
```

// Handler :

1. Important is to check for DataGridCells etc, so we use IsDescendantOf() method to check if some element which lies in our DataGrid is having focus.
2. Take note of e.Handled and set it's value accordingly.

   ```
   private void FrameworkPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (sender is FrameworkElement)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).ToString());
               if (!((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).IsDescendantOf(MyDataGrid))
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine("Datagrid lost focus completely !");
                   //e.Handled = true;

                   // Do something now
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :)